# How Can I get id from link with ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm working on a reactjS PROJECT and I want To get the id of the selected item in a link to fetch the details.
this is how I consume the api :

```
const [selectedComplain, setSelectedComplain] = useState([]);

async function getComplain(compl_id) {
  setSelectedComplain(compl_id)
  console.warn(compl_id)
  let result = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/getComp/` + compl_id);
  result = await result.json();
  console.warn(result)
}
```

This is the Link part :

```
<Link to={`/complain/details/`} compl_id={selectedComplain}>
  <span onClick={()=>getComplain(item.compl_id)}>
    {item.compl_title}
  </span>
</Link>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone will try to help me

Comment: ***Where*** are you wanting to get an id value from? Can you explain what isn't working as expected?

Comment: @DrewReese in the next page which has path '/complain/details/' . Actually I'm working on notification I want when I click on a specifi item I redirect to another page which has the details of the selected item in notification

Comment: place the id inside the path `/complain/details/${selectedComplain.id} then in your /complain/details/:id you can use the useParams hook that is provided by react-router-dom to get the :id. but first you must set it in your routes. E.g. <Route path='/complain/details/:complainId' then when you use useParams you would then get the id

Comment: @DylanL. I followed your instructions bu for the id I get always undefined

Comment: Make sure and take a look at this documentation. It's the best I can do for you now that the question is closed. 

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams